# How do I use puppet to execute a script on a linux VM

Tags: puppet

I need puppet to execute a script that is inside an installed app. In addition I need to run only if it detects an older version of the and is not on a certain server and then install the new version

I have tried a bunch of stuff and I am losing track. First I tried to use a cd to go to the where the script and then tried running the script directly but I keep getting the same error.

install.pp

```
# Install required packages
class tripwire::install {

  exec { 'uninstall_tripwire':
    command => './usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/bin/uninstall.sh',
    cwd     => '/usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/bin',
    path    => '/usr/bin/sh',

    onlyif  => [
                  "${::fqdn} != 'server.com'",
                  '/usr/bin/test -f 
/usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/bin/uninstall.sh',
                  "grep -c '8.6.0' /usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/data/version",
      ],
    notify  => Exec['install_tripwire'],
```

I would think this would it would execute the script but all I get is:
Error: /Stage[main]/Tripwire::Install/Exec[uninstall_tripwire]: Could not evaluate: Could not find command 'server.com'

Comment: For what you appear to be trying to accomplish, wouldn't `package { 'tripwire': ensure => 'latest' }` be better in pretty much every way?

Comment: ... unless, of course, you didn't install tripwire from a package in the first place (which probably would have been a mistake).

Comment: No we are not installing via a package.

Answer (score 2):

> I need puppet to execute a script that is inside an installed app. In
>   addition I need to run only if it detects an older version of the and
>   is not on a certain server and then install the new version

The particular task you seem to be trying to perform with your `Exec` duplicates standard behavior of the `Package` resource.  You really, *really* ought to manage software via packages, even if you have to do some packaging yourself and maintain a local package repository.  The time spent on packaging is easily offset by the time saved managing software, even with Puppet in the mix.

Additionally, as far as controlling which machines to operate upon goes, you ought to be treating that as a matter of classification.  If that class should not be applied to machine `server.com` then it should not be declared into that machine's catalog.  If it should be applied differently to that machine than to others, then it should be appropriately parameterized, and those parameters used (at classification time, maybe with the help of Hiera) to select the appropriate behavior for each target machine.

Nevertheless, with respect to the code actually presented, the error message

> Could not evaluate: Could not find command 'server.com'

reflects that this element of your `onlyif` array ...

> ```
>                   "${::fqdn} != 'server.com'",
> ```

... is not a command.  `onlyif` requires a command or an array of them that can be executed on the target system, so maybe this, instead:

```
                  "test ${::fqdn} != server.com",
```

Additionally, this looks wrong:

> ```
>     command => './usr/local/tripwire/te/agent/bin/uninstall.sh',
> ```

Remove the leading `.`, unless you really intend to resolve that path against the working directory. And if you *do* intend to resolve it as a relative path then I urge you to instead expand it to an absolute one.

Furthermore, this probably doesn't do what you intend:

> ```
>     path    => '/usr/bin/sh',
> ```

The `path` attribute names a binary search path, like the `PATH` environment variable.  You may indeed want to specify one, such as maybe `'/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin'`, but if the intention of what you did put was for the commmand to be executed via a shell, then you were looking for

```
    provider => 'shell',
```

Comment: John, thank you so much. That worked! Everything is working now. I started looking at how to use package to keep me up to date.